# 'Until which' as relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

*These dangerous goods, until which are delivered to the place of storage, must be packed inside shock-absorbing materials.*

Does this sound wrong or hard to be comprehended? If it does, what's the better way to rewrite while keeping the order?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "keeping the order," and perhaps say why it is necessary to keep it so? As it stands, the sentence is non-standard. Most suggested rewrites are going to want to move the "until."

Answer (score 2):

Original:

> These dangerous goods, until which are delivered to the place of storage, must be packed inside shock-absorbing materials. (bad grammar)

You can't say "until which" because this sentence structure doesn't need a relative pronoun.

This sentence should be rewritten in one of these ways:

1. UNTIL these dangerous goods are delivered to the place of storage, THEY must be packed....
2. These dangerous goods must be packed... UNTIL THEY are delivered to....
3. These dangerous goods must be packed....UNTIL SUCH TIME as THEY are delivered....

Answer (score -2):

> *These dangerous goods, until which are delivered to the place of storage, must be packed inside shock-absorbing materials.*

Your original sentence is broken. You definitely can't use "*which*" after "*until*".

- "*These dangerous goods, which...*" is okay, but it's not what you want.

What I'd probably say as a non-native speaker is:

- "*These dangerous goods, before being delivered to the place of storage, must be packed inside shock-absorbing materials.*"